# Need Help Using Update statement in a CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a CTE to create a Flag=1 for each IndividualID where the A1.InfantSum > A2.InfantSum and the query works the way it should:

```
WITH ATQInfant_CTE AS 
(
    SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ATQInfant_IndividualID ORDER BY ATQInfant_CreateDate) AS rownum
    FROM 
        [dbo].[vCDCP_rptInfantImprove]
)
SELECT DISTINCT 
    A1.ATQInfant_IndividualID,
    A1.ATQInfant_CreateDate,
    A1.InfantSum,
    A2.InfantSum,
    CASE 
       WHEN A1.InfantSum > A2.InfantSum THEN 1 ELSE 0 
    END AS flag
FROM
    ATQInfant_CTE AS A1
INNER JOIN
    ATQInfant_CTE AS A2 ON A1.ATQInfant_IndividualID = A2.ATQInfant_IndividualID 
                        AND A1.rownum = A2.rownum + 1
```

I get the following result, but need to have the Flag=0 if the IndividualID has more than one '1'.

[image]

I'm not sure how to incorporate the Update part to the query so that I can set the Flag to 0 if the IndividualID has more than one '1' in the flag. When I add the Update query to the end, it does not recognize 'Flag' as  a column name in the query: Can someone let me know how I can add the Update query to the CTE?

```
UPDATE [dbo].[vCDCP_rptInfantImprove]
SET flag = '0'
WHERE flag = 1 AND a2.rownum + 1 > 1
```

What the new query results look like:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THis query will give you the rows that are not the latest occurence of ATQInfant_IndividualID

```
Select * from [dbo].[vCDCP_rptInfantImprove] a
where exists(select 1 from [dbo].[vCDCP_rptInfantImprove] b where a.ATQInfant_IndividualID  = b.ATQInfant_IndividualID a.ATQInfant_CreateDate < b.ATQInfant_CreateDate)
```

if those are the ones you want to flag to zero, do:

```
    update a
    set flag = '0'
    from [dbo].[vCDCP_rptInfantImprove] a
    where exists(select 1 from [dbo].[vCDCP_rptInfantImprove] b where a.ATQInfant_IndividualID  = b.ATQInfant_IndividualID a.ATQInfant_CreateDate < b.ATQInfant_CreateDate)

Adjustement of first query:
THe flag is 1 only if it doesnt exist a line with the same ATQInfant_IndividualID  that is not more recent.
Let us know 

    WITH ATQInfant_CTE AS 
    (
        SELECT
            *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ATQInfant_IndividualID ORDER BY ATQInfant_CreateDate) AS rownum
        FROM 
            [dbo].[vCDCP_rptInfantImprove]
    )
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        A1.ATQInfant_IndividualID,
        A1.ATQInfant_CreateDate,
        A1.InfantSum,
        A2.InfantSum,
        CASE 
           WHEN 
A1.InfantSum > A2.InfantSum and
not exists(select 1 from ATQInfant_CTE A3 where A1.ATQInfant_IndividualID = A3.ATQInfant_IndividualID and A1.ATQInfant_CreateDate < A3.ATQInfant_CreateDate) THEN 1 ELSE 0 
        END AS flag
    FROM
        ATQInfant_CTE AS A1
    INNER JOIN
        ATQInfant_CTE AS A2 ON A1.ATQInfant_IndividualID = A2.ATQInfant_IndividualID 
                            AND A1.rownum = A2.rownum + 1
```

Comment: Where would I incorporate the second query you posted into my CTE query?

Comment: Hey Dee, I have added the query asjustement at the bottom of my reply. This should give you what you are looking for

Comment: Now I'm getting an error "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'U' to data type int." I already put a where clause in the view 'vCDCP_rptInfantImprove' for <> U for the InfantSum

Comment: I used CAST to resolve the data type conversion error, but the query still isnt doing what I need. Also, the key piece of the query is missing, 'CASE 
       WHEN A1.InfantSum > A2.InfantSum THEN 1 ELSE 0 
    END AS flag'

Comment: Hi Dee, I have updated the query to add A1.InfantSum > A2.InfantSum. Can you try again please?

Comment: Now with the new code I'm getting the data conversion error again.

Comment: Re-implement in it the CAST you used to resolve the data type conversion error.

Comment: It isnt putting a flag of 1 for A1.InfantSum > A2.InfantSum when there is more than one of the same IndividualID. I attached the table results above

Comment: I think it works. I think its just not taking into account the seconds from the CreateDate